# Azure Container Registry (ACR) SKUs

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry

What is the difference between the Azure Container Registry (ACR) SKUs? The CLI lists these as options:

```
-sku {Basic,Managed_Basic,Managed_Standard,Managed_Premium}
```

The [pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/container-registry/) provides some help, but doesn't describe the difference between Basic and Managed_Basic. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr#create) are not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Azure container registry, there are two different kinds of storage account, unmanaged disk and managed disk.

When we chose `managed registry`, we can chose SKUs, like Basic, Standard, Premium.

Enable this feature to have Azure automatically manage the registry without creating and managing storage accounts on your own. **Managed registries have additional support for webhooks, AAD, and repository delete**.
[image]

Pricing tiers for managed registries provide different levels of **performance** and **capacity**:

[image]

> Managed Registry - A tier that offers additional capabilities for
>   registries in three SKUs - Basic, Standard, and Premium. The images in
>   these SKUs are stored in Storage Accounts managed by the Azure
>   Container Registries service, which improves reliability and enables
>   new features. New capabilities include webhook integration, repository
>   authentication with Azure Active Directory, and support for delete
>   functionality.

More information about managed registry, please refer to this [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/container-registry/container-registry-intro.md).

About unmanaged registry, user should to create a registry backed by their **own Storage Accounts** when creating registries.